# PostgreSQL 9.3's REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW command only lasts for length of Django connection

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, materialized-views

I've got a materialized view in PostgreSQL that I would like to update periodically. When I try to update it manually from the Django manage.py shell, the command to refresh the materialized view successfully completes, but the changes seem to disappear after I leave the shell. For example, on my first session, these are the commands that I run:

```
>>> Model.objects.get(...).subscribers.count
2L
>>> RefreshMaterializedViews()
>>> Model.objects.get(...).subscribers.count
3L
```

I then exit from the shell, go back in, and run the query again:

```
>>> Model.objects.get(...).subscribers.count
2L
```

The `RefreshMaterializedViews` function is written like this:

```
def RefreshMaterializedViews():
    for materialized_view in MATERIALIZED_VIEWS:
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        try:
            cursor.execute("REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW %s;" % materialized_view)
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

So, it seems that PostgreSQL only bothered to refresh the materialized view for the current connection. On the other hand, going into the database shell itself and simply running `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW xxx;` works.

Comment: This sounds like you do not **`COMMIT`** your transaction and all your changes are rolled back. Is your client running with `autocommit`?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you forgot:

```
connection.commit()
```